# sin() output of a double coming out as 0.00000. (C language)

Tags: c, math.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    double interval;
    
    for(i=0;i<30;i++) 
        {
        interval = i/10.0;
        printf("sin(%lf) = %lf \t", interval, abs(sin(interval)));
        };
    printf("\n+++++++++\n");
    return 0;
}
```

the sin value of each interval term is coming out to be 0.000000. example sin(0.60000) = 0.000000

Comment: enable all warnings and you'll know the reason

Comment: Bishal Hazarika, Tip, use `"%g"` rather than `"%f"` for debugging floating point problems.  It is more informative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`abs`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/abs) function is an *integer* function. Which means you have *undefined behavior* since you use the mismatching format specifier `%lf`.

For floating point you need to use [`fabs`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fabs).

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem. Last thanks comment was deleted idk why

Answer (score 1):

The `abs` from `stdlib.h` has signature with `int`s so yours doubles are downcasted:

```
int abs(int x)
```

Use this one from `math.h`

```
double fabs(double x)
```

From: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fabs.htm

Answer (score 0):

printf("sin(%lf) = %lf \t", interval, abs(sin(interval))); change this line with
printf("sin(%lf) = %lf \t", interval, fabs(sin(interval)));